# Babel file structure is duplicating

Tags: babeljs

Using latest babel preset.  My .babelrc contains

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

In my package.json, I run it as follows:

```
"build:babel": "babel app.js app/** venue/** -d build",
```

My original code structure is:

[image]

But after running babel my build folder looks like the following:

[image]

The problem I'm seeing is that it's building the file in the sub-directories correctly but it also putting it into the root build folder.  Example: "containers" is in the build folder under app/plugins/containers which is correct.  But its also in the root build folder.  Also, the files "border, button, card, checkbox, click, color_picker, ..." belong in other sub-directories (which it is), but is also in the root build folder.

I'm wondering if I'm running it incorrectly?